# Javascript - remove preceding tabs in function string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some function declared in javascript, with some tabs at the start of lines, e.g.:

```
{
    x: function() {
        alert('message');
    }
}
```

now, I have another function (I'm trying to create something like PHP XDebug extension var_dump), where I want to get that function as a string. I use `obj.x.toString()`. Problem is, those tabs ("\t") at starts of line is messing up tabbing in var_dump output. So I need a function, that would find line with least tabs or spaces at the beginning and then cut off that amount of white space from the beggining of other lines.

So, for example:

```
    function() {
        if (0 == 0) { //whatever
            ...
        }
    }
```

should become:

```
function() {
    if (0 == 0) { //whatever
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm looking for some kind of regex,..., not some function bigger than anything other I have in my script. If it can't be done simply, I can just leave it out. It is just nice to have feature, not requirement.

Comment: what about tabs and spaces mixed? If yes, then how much spaces equals one tab? What about significant white-space (where the script-source is in Unix-line endings and the author has used an `\ ` (escape) at the end of the line in a string? What about `x.toSource()` (given it's just a feature)?

Comment: I don't think you can do this without potentially clobbering string literals with newlines and tabs in them, like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvermie/thL76/)

Comment: can you regex it in java?

Comment: Match `/^(?:\t| {4})*/`, on the match replace `/ {4}/g` with `"\t"`, get length, split newlines, map with a trim, re-join. May still break literals containing new lines